# Should the author link in GIS.se blog posts link to user profile on GIS.se?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blog

Looking at [Kirk's latest post](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/calculation-and-compilation-in-arcmap/), I noticed the author name and link:

[image]

When you click on this link, it takes you to a archive of all posts by that author, which if I'm not mistaken, is a default feature of WordPress. Two things:

1. Should this link carry you to the authors [user profile on GIS.se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/59/kirk-kuykendall?tab=stats)? This of course begs the question of shouldn't there be a list of the users blog posts on their profile as well (they should get credit for them of course)?
2. Shouldn't Kirk's WordPress user name get sanitized to his GIS.se user name? I think this has already sorta been brought up, and is related to the two systems not being connected.

Comment: See identity mgmt in this thread: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/614/should-se-roll-their-own-blogging-software